# Laravel 4 database constraints

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I defined relations between different models(belongsto(), hasmany()).
do I have to add the foreign key constraints also in the database?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need to add the FKs in a separate migration after all your table migrations. 
Refer to the docs for any additional details. 
http://laravel.com/docs/schema#creating-and-dropping-tables

Comment: I'm working directly on the database, I'm not using a migration I add the constraints and when I save a record I have an sql exception.

Comment: Well then the title of your question is misleading. Laravel 4 has nothing to do with databases or constraints if you're not using migrations or eloquent. I suggest posting the exact nature of your exception and being more descriptive with your problem. Possibly reading how Fks work in mysql would be helpful to you as well.